# Ajax send, Can I know if the user "comes" from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Example:

When you use "ajax.send", you see the file (like this "post.php?q=...".) But If you copy that "url" and paste it into your browser (same parameters), you can also access.

So, can I block it?.

Comment: Yes, and no. Yes, you can detect if it is or isn't ajax and change the output, but no, you can't completely block it because it can be easily spoofed. Blocking it is not worth the effort because anyone who would want to see it would also know how to spoof it (or to inspect their network tab)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Every request, let it be AJAX or not, can be simulated by browser (tools).